# Setting strokeColor to a CardView programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview, materialcardview

I'm trying setting `strokeColor` programmatically but it isn't working. Here's what I've tried

```
gold_card.strokeColor= Color.GREEN
```

Looking at official method of strokeColor, it needs a parameter

```
public void setStrokeColor(@ColorInt int strokeColor) {
    this.cardViewHelper.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
}
```

So, upon passing Color int parameter, it says unreachable code. Below method says unreachable code

```
gold_card.strokeColor(Color.GRAY)
```

So how to set `strokeColor` to a `CardView` the correct way?
PS: Yes, I'm using `MaterailCardView`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `gold_card` as `MatericalCardView`, not `CardView`.

```
MatrialCardView gold_card = findViewById(R.id.cold_card)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method **`setStrokeColor`**:

```
gold_card.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.xxxx));
```

Also make sure to set the strokeWidth (in the layout with `app:strokeWidth` or programmatically with the method `setStrokeWidth()`) because the default value is `0dp`

Answer (score 0):

Change to...

```
gold_card.strokeColor(R.color.GRAY);
```

or

```
gold_card.strokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GRAY));
```

or

```
gold_card.strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9")); //your color code
```

Comment: Expression 'strokeColor' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Comment: I already said, passing parameter says unreachable statement.